# The certificate is not correctly signed by the trusted CA

Tags: amazon-web-services

please I'm asking for help...

I'm working with the stm32l475 IoT node board actually I'm dealing with the x-cube cmdgen-IoT-cloud-generic package which necessitates an aws amazon account for the iot application. Actually I'm using tera term as a terminal for the visualization after loading the firmware into the board it asks me to insert those things below:

```
-Enter the connection string of your device:
template with MQTT authentication:    HostName=xxx;HostPort=xxx;ConnSecurity=x;MQClientId=xxx;MQUserName=xxx;MQUserPwd=xxx;
template without MQTT authentication: HostName=xxx;HostPort=xxx;ConnSecurity=x;MQClientId=xxx;
(in this case, I'm using mqtt template and I'm putting the hostname as "a376ne315hxclq-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")
-IoT device connection parameters
-the root CA certificate
-the device certificate
-device key
```

I want to ask if the device key is the private key that I get when I'm generating the aws account or something else because I have this error after applying the private key :

```
ERROR: net_sock_open_mbedtls L#327 Server verification:
  ! The certificate is not correctly signed by the trusted CA

ERROR: net_sock_open_mbedtls L#334  failed
  ! mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x2700
ERROR: genericmqtt_client_XCube_sample_run L#451 Could not open the socket at a376ne315hxclq-ats.iot.us-east-2.amazonaws.com port 8883.
../../../../../../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/library/ssl_tls.c:4587: x509_verify_cert() returned -9984 (-0x2700)
```

Comment: When you create things  which certificate you have used?

Comment: I tried for the root ca:  AmazonRootCA3  or VeriSign-Class 3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5, after I used the device certificate and for the device key I used the private key.